# onPostExecute method not running

Tags: php, android

The problem is onPostExecute method is not running actually,the code stops after executing onPreExecute.After entering credentials ,and clicking login button it is showing "Login status" only,but not the result i.e "Login success" or "login not success" from the php file,or you can say onPostExecute method is returning null String value.Please help.I am not getting this.

```
 public class BackgroundWorker extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
        Context context;
        AlertDialog alertDialog;
        BackgroundWorker (Context ctx) {
            context = ctx;
        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String type = params[0];
            String login_url = "http://127.0.0.1/login3.php";
            if(type.equals("login")) {
                try {
                    String user_name = params[1];
                    String password = params[2];
                    URL url = new URL(login_url);
                    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                    httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                    httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                    OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                    String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("user_name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(user_name,"UTF-8")+"&"
                            +URLEncoder.encode("passwords","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8");
                    bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
                    bufferedWriter.flush();
                    bufferedWriter.close();
                    outputStream.close();
                    InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
                    String result="";
                    String line="";
                    while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null) {
                        result += line;
                    }
                    bufferedReader.close();
                    inputStream.close();
                    httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                    return result;
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
           alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Login Status");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            alertDialog.setMessage(result);
            alertDialog.show();
        }

    }


PHP FILE USED FOR CONNECTION-->

<?PHP
require "conn.php";
$user_name=$_POST["user_name"];
$user_pass=$_POST["passwords"];
$mysql_qry="select * from login_db where email_id like '$user_name' and password like '$user_pass';";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$mysql_qry);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
{echo "Login success";}

else
    {echo "Login not success";}

?>
```

Comment: are you passing Activity as the context? or the applicationContext?

Comment: do you get exceptions in logcat?

Comment: @Pooya Yes I am getting this exception--"04-15 16:55:25.946 6882-7138/com.example.somya.client_feedback_application W/System.err: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /127.0.0.1 (port 80): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)"

Comment: @SomyaArora the exception is pretty clear that you cannot connect to your server

Comment: @rushabhshah..that I dont't know.Even I dont know the difference between them.I have copied this code form somewhere.

Comment: @Pooya..But where is the problem.Why it is not connecting?My php code is connected to localhost port 80..that I have checked and verified.Then where is the problem

Comment: Use your ip address to connect to your service

Comment: localhost is your android phone's ip. Not your server.

Comment: @rushabhshah1693 That is what I am using,but still its not working

Comment: @SomyaArora if you are connecting to another server you should use that IP instead of "127.0.0.1" which is localhost

Comment: That is your localhost ip, you need to check your ip from cmd, use ipconfig, get the ip which is like 192.xxx.xxx.xxx. Use that..

Comment: I have edited it to---String login_url = "http:// 192.168.1.4/login3.php";..But still it does not work

Comment: @SomyaArora Check for the same url(with ip) in your browser if it is working then it should work in app too,has the error changed?

Comment: @rushabhshah1693 No its not working in the browser too.And the error is same code is still not running the onPostExecute method.

Comment: @SomyaArora Your server is not set correctly, you need to work on that part first.

Comment: @rushabhshah1693 Sorry,But i think there is some problem in my php code.First let me correct it.Then I will get back to you.

Comment: @rushabhshah1693.Hey,my php file is running on this http://localhost/login3.php only.And i entered the same in my android project code but nothing changed.

Comment: @SomyaArora Your server localhost is different from android's localhost..when you use localhost from your app,it will look for localhost on the mobile device.In order to get data from your local server in your app,you will need the server to work on ip address. 192.168.1.4

Comment: @SomyaArora If you are using wamp server make sure you click on "put server online" this will make sure it works on your ip address too

Comment: Thanks @rushabhshah1693

Answer (score -1):

For running it on genymotion emulator use url--->

```
String login_url = `"http://10.0.3.2:8080/login3.php";`
```

And for android device use--->`

```
String login_url = "http://192.168.*.*/login3.php";`
```